# RSA, cryptography

Tags: abstract-algebra, cryptography

Consider the RSA system with $n=55$ and $e=17$, where $e$ is the encryption key. Now encrypting $9$ gives

$c_1 =  9^e = 4$ mod $5$

$c_2 =  9^e = 4$ mod $11$.

Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem I get $c=9^e$ = $4$ mod $55$.
Now assume that there was a mistake in the computation of $9^e$ mod $5$ and you got $2$ instead of $4$. $(c_1' =9^e = 2)$

This will lead to $c' = 37$ mod $55$.

How can I find the factorisation of $n$ by knowing $c$ and $c'$?

I thought the Chinese Remainder Theorem might be helpful since we then have:

$a\cdot p \cdot c_2 + b \cdot q \cdot c_1 = 4$ mod $55$

$a\cdot p \cdot c_2 + b \cdot q \cdot c_1' = 37$ mod $55$

where $a,b$ are such that $a \cdot p + b \cdot q = 1$, and hence

$b \cdot q \cdot (c_1' - c_1) = 33$ mod $55$.

But here I don't know how to proceed.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I can not understand your question. Could you give an example of how you have tried to solve it?

Comment: so you need to know the factorization in order to find the factorization? Im confused

Comment: 9 is not equal to 4 mod 11.

Answer (score 0):

In the way you have presented it, I don't think this is solvable. Unless the "mistake" in computation was done in a very specific way, I don't see how a wrong computation could help you break RSA. Is this an exercise in a textbook? If so, could you post the exact text?

Comment: The exercise can be found in the Cryptography exam 2011 here: http://www.math.uzh.ch/index.php?file&key1=26815 exercise 4

Comment: Notice that you aren't encrypting to get c. You're doing a **digital signature**. That is, $c = m^d$. Try again with that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

We know $c' = c$ mod $q$, therefore $c'-c = 0$ mod $q$. This means $c'-c$ is a multiple of $q$. Hence $gcd(c'-c,n)=q$

In our example $gcd(37-4,55) = gcd(33,55) = 11$